Filebeat - Log Processing Issues/Delay/Data Loss
We are experiencing significant challenges with log processing on three of our hosts. Each of these hosts runs nine services, generating between 30,000 to 72,000 events per minute per log file. The server specifications include a 16-core CPU and 62 GB of memory.
We have observed a delay of approximately 20 minutes in log processing. Additionally, after each hour when log files rotate and are renamed, Filebeat does not read data from the previous files. This results in the loss of the last 10 to 20 minutes of log data.
In comparison, our other nine hosts(3 + 9 hosts in one application. Other apps data collection also works well), which have three to five log files configured, are processing data efficiently without any issues.
To diagnose the problem, I executed the command GET _cat/thread_pool/bulk?v, which did not show any rejected requests, indicating that the bulk thread pool is functioning as expected.
How to resolve these issues and improve log processing on the affected hosts?
A] Filebeat/ELK Version: 8.3.1 (12 Node Platinum License)
B] Events per minute.
Service1 - 60k events/min
Service2 - 15k events/min
Service3 - 500 events/min
Service4 - 17k events/min
Service5 - 15.5k events/min
Service6 - 40k events/min
Service7 - 100 events/min
Service8 - 78k events/min
Service9 - 160k events/min

C] Following is a filebeat.yml
filebeat.config.modules:
  enabled: true
  path: ${path.config}/modules.d/*.yml
  reload.enabled: true
  reload.period: 10s

queue.mem:
  events: 20000
  #events: 20000 (tried 8192 as well)
  flush.min_events: 2048

filebeat.registry.flush: 5s

output.logstash:
  hosts: [ "10.40.7.40:5045", "10.40.7.41:5044", "10.40.7.42:5045", "10.40.7.40:5044", "10.40.7.41:5045", "10.40.7.42:5044" ]
  loadbalance: true
  workers: 12
  #workers: 8 ( tried 8 as well)
  bulk_max_size: 20000
  #bulk_max_size: 15000 (tried this as well)
  flush_interval: 1s
  #flush_interval: 500ms (tried this as well)

D] modules.d/app.yml
Note: After each one hour, file gets renamed to "app1-2024-10-16-19-1.log" where "19" is previous hour.
- module: app-1
  microservice:
    enabled: true
    var.paths:
      - "/path/to/app1.log"
    input:
      scan_frequency: 3s  
      close_renamed: false
      close_inactive: 30m
      ignore_older: 24h
      clean_inactive: 48h
      close_timeout: 2h

E] I have 3 logstash hosts which has 12 core cpu and 23 gb memory. I have set pipeline.batch_size to 2048
F] Sample Application log - response string (It prints request/response & things in between of transaction, but format of log is same)

2024-06-13 17:50:20:815 [app4] [app-services] [INFO ] [https-jsse-nio-9443-exec-38] [c7dd483c-2461-4ee5-8d67-bd5076129460] [858f223f1ffe4b8c] [858f223f1ffe4b8c] [] [ResponseLogFilter:100] - TraceId= [c7dd483c-d5076129460] Timestamp= [1718281219341] ClientId= [abcd] AuthMethod= [JOSE] RequestMethod= [POST] ContentType= [application/jose] AcceptType= [application/jose] RequestUri= [/abcd/efg/create] RequestIp= [0.0.0.0] ResponseBody= [{"error_type":"api_validation_error","error_code":"T3","message":"testing test","status":422}] KeyId= [bdbhsbsa-bsbbsbwh8QaCek] Algorithm= [null] ServerAuthorization= [null] Status= [422] ResponseDate= [2024-06-13T17:50:20+0530] ErrorType= [api_validation_error] ErrorCode= [T3] ErrorMessage= [Testing Testing] Latency= [27]

G] Filebeat log

{"log.level":"info","@timestamp":"2024-10-16T20:23:08.455+0530","log.logger":"monitoring","log.origin":{"file.name":"log/log.go","file.line":185},"message":"Non-zero metrics in the last 30s","service.name":"filebeat","monitoring":{"metrics":{"beat":{"cgroup":{"cpuacct":{"total":{"ns":299461410874}},"memory":{"mem":{"usage":{"bytes":13615104}}}},"cpu":{"system":{"ticks":1140,"time":{"ms":360}},"total":{"ticks":20510,"time":{"ms":7210},"value":0},"user":{"ticks":19370,"time":{"ms":6850}}},"info":{"ephemeral_id":"9dadf2d8-7ad2-43c5-9726-5e33fbb455c8","uptime":{"ms":90114},"version":"8.3.1"},"memstats":{"gc_next":215038376,"memory_alloc":157361792,"memory_sys":4194304,"memory_total":3315695936,"rss":335130624},"runtime":{"goroutines":116}},"filebeat":{"events":{"active":-4,"added":110716,"done":110720},"harvester":{"open_files":0,"running":0}},"libbeat":{"config":{"module":{"running":9},"scans":3},"output":{"events":{"acked":102528,"active":12288,"batches":55,"total":110720},"read":{"bytes":336},"write":{"bytes":22499231}},"pipeline":{"clients":9,"events":{"active":20025,"published":110720,"total":110716},"queue":{"acked":110720}}},"registrar":{"states":{"current":0}},"system":{"load":{"1":13.72,"15":15.51,"5":14.25,"norm":{"1":0.8575,"15":0.9694,"5":0.8906}}}},"ecs.version":"1.6.0"}}


Tldr;
In my honest opinion you have 2 issues:

Lossing logs
Delay in processing

While I don't think we can tell yet. It does seems that the filebeat would be the weak link at ingest because when the file rotate you loose as much log as you have delay.
Lossing logs
You have created a custom module. In order to fully investigate this issue we would need to have access to the config file of your microservice module.
What I am going to assume is that inside the config.yml of you module you are using a custom file_identity maybe not based on the inode. Which upon being renamed is:

Identified as a new file by beats
No part of the targets set in your path: /path/to/app1.log only match a specific file

So most probably you have something to change in the config/microservice.yml.
Ressources to investigate:

How to create a module in filebeat.
file_identity for log type
file_identity for stream type

Performance
Again some assumptions, it sounds like you do not know which component is inducing the latency.
What I could suggest is:

Monitoring of both logstash and filebeat
Add some timestamp in your logs for:

When the log has been read by filebeat
When the log is in logstash
When the log reach elasticsearch's ingest pipeline



This should help you identify the component introducing the issue.

Thank you for your response. I identified and resolved the issue a few weeks ago. The root cause was back pressure. To address this, I set up two input pipelines on ports 5044 and 5045, directing logs to the same filter pipelines. Additionally, I deployed three more Logstash instances. Everything is functioning smoothly now.
